# What happened to the Slitheen's ship?

Tags: doctor-who

Been re-watching the series on Netflix and after the two parter "Aliens of London" and "World War 3" everything seems neatly dealt with except that there was still a spaceship parked in the Thames.

Was the fate of the ship ever covered in any related media or is it just gathering dust in the warehouse next to the Ark of the Covenant?

Comment: "It belongs in a museum!"

Comment: I always assumed that UNIT took care of it when they retrieved the pig-pilot.

Answer (score 3):

It's never stated what happened to that particular ship. However, when we run into [Blon Fel-Fotch](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Blon_Fel-Fotch_Passameer-Day_Slitheen) again in the episode "[Boom Town](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Blon_Fel-Fotch_Passameer-Day_Slitheen)", we discover her plan to basically blow up the Earth and use her extrapolator surfboard to ride the resulting wave to freedom.

Given that she needs to do something quite so drastic and ridiculous to get off Earth, we can safely assume that the Slitheen craft in the Thames is damaged beyond repair, or too secure to get her hands on, or both.

I think @Tim is close with his comment, but given how early in the series these episodes with the Slitheen family occur, I think it's more likely that Torchwood took the craft, not UNIT. As a result, there's a good chance it was lying around somewhere amongst the other Alien paraphernalia when the 10th Doctor, Rose and Jackie were taken to Torchwood Tower in Canary Wharf.

As Yvonne says: "If it's alien, it's ours".

Comment: Bear in mind, the craft that crashed was only a decoy, complete with fake pilot.  It is very likely not actually a working ship, just filled with enough high-tech widgets and nernies to keep Earth scientists busy, believing it's a real ship. Far cheaper than crashing a real one.

Comment: The heck are "nernies"?

Comment: Another term for widgets; fiddly bits, frippery.